# At the time of button click open another one application?

Tags: android

I have a two application. **ApplicationA** and **ApplicationB** .From the ApplicationA I have to open the ApplicationB.At the same time i need to send some detail to ApplicationB .How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this one by writing just 1 line of code

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(this,"Here second app package name like com.urproject.urclass.class");
```

For send to some details means you can use bundle or sharedpreference or declaring static and access by using class name.

```
Bundle extras = mIntent.getExtras();
extras.putString(key, value);
```

Answer (score 0):

**First Context (can be Activity/Service etc)**

You have a few options:

1) Use the [Bundle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html) from the [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html):

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, Example.class);
Bundle extras = mIntent.getExtras();
extras.putString(key, value);
```

2) Create a new Bundle

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, Example.class);
Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();
mBundle.extras.putString(key, value);
mIntent.putExtras(mBundle);
```

3) Use the [putExtra()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])) shortcut method of the Intent

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, Example.class);
mIntent.putExtra(key, value);
```

**New Context (can be Activity/Service etc)**

```
Intent myIntent = getIntent(); // this getter is just for example purpose, can differ
if (myIntent !=null && myIntent.getExtras()!=null)
     String value = myIntent.getExtras().getString(key);
}
```

***NOTE:*** Bundles have "get" and "put" methods for all the primitive types, Parcelables, and Serializables. I just used Strings for demonstrational purposes.